# How to get a continuous minutely aggregate with pandas?

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a db table containing a datetime column with values stretching over 24hours. If I use pandas dataframe groupby function to give a minute by minute aggregation, this will throw everything into 0-59 buckets regardless of which hour they were in.

How do I get minute by minute aggregations spread over the timeframe of the table, in this case 24 hours? Also, for those minutes in which there is no values in the table, how do I insert a zero count for that minute into the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `pd.TimeGroupper`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range("11:00", "21:30", freq="100ms"))
df['x'] = 1

g = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('S')).sum()
```